# write javascript with jsf

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

I'm learning jsf, using PrimeFaces.
I have an array of integers in a Bean that I would write as a var in javascript.
The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ChartJS  {

    private LinkedList <Integer> datos = new LinkedList();
```

I want to pass the var datos  to an integer array in javascript.
I succeeded declaring a String variable and transform it into the javascript, but I guess that is not the right way to do it.

In bean

```
private String datosS;
....
for (Integer i : datos ){
    datosS+= String.ValueOf(i) + " ";

}
```

In view.xhtml

```
var intArray = '#{chartJS.datosS}'.split(" ").map(Number).filter(Boolean);
...
```

I would like to know is how to create a javascript var.
Like this

In view.xhtml

```
var data = {

 datasets: [

    //Iterator itr = #{chartJS.datos}.iterator();
    //while(itr.hasNext()) {
        //Integer i = (Integer) itr.next();
             {
                name: "data num " + i,
                data: i             
             }
        //if (itr.hasNext()){
            ,
        //} 
    //}

    ]};
```

Sorry for my English.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work like this, and you wouldn't need `String datosS`:

```
var data = {

    datasets: [
        <ui:repeat value="#{chartJS.datos}" var="currentInt">
            {
                name: "data num " + #{currentInt},
                data: #{currentInt}
            }
            ,
        </ui:repeat>
        null
    ]
};
```